# How to resize a JavaFX 3D SubScene?

Tags: java, javafx

[This code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/camera.htm#CJAHFAHB) will create a 3d scene that is 300x300 large. The viewport won't resize when I resize the containing window/stage.

`Parent` doesn't have any `width` or `height` properties. How do I adjust the size of the `Parent` and/or `SubScene` to the changing window size?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

bind it to the parent

```
SubScene subscene = new SubScene(root, 1024, 768, true, null);
subscene.setFill(Color.GREY);
subscene.setCamera(camera);
StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
stackPane.getChildren().add(subscene);
subscene.heightProperty().bind(stackPane.heightProperty());
subscene.widthProperty().bind(stackPane.widthProperty());
```

Comment: I found out about that some time ago, but thanks nevertheless.

Comment: Parent class does not contain a heightProperty() or widthProperty().

Comment: what parent class are you using? can you add a stackpane inside the parent class and then bind subscene?

Answer (score 6):

I found it is also important to set the managed property of the SubScene object to false.

```
subscene.setManaged(false);
```

This way, the SubScene object's size will not impact the size of its parent StackPane object and resizing will also work when reducing the StackPane object's size.

Comment: Just what I needed to shrink the sub scene

Answer (score 0):

With the following approach you can put your SubScene into any class that extends the Pane class (e.g. BorderPane, GridPane, etc.). Also the subScene can have a different size from your Pane:

```
public class GuiControler extends BorderPane implements Initializable,ChangeListener {

    //Set a changeListener to the Stage's Window and Implement the ChangeListener in the class where you want to make the subScene scaling.

    stage.widthProperty().addListener(this);
    stage.heightProperty().addListener(this); 

 //....


     @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                double width = stage.getWidth();
                double height = stage.getHeight();
                if(observable.equals(this.widthProperty())) {
                    double scale = width / 400; // 400 is my initial width size of the stage (main java app window) window
                    subScene.setWidth(200*scale); // 200 is my initial size of the subscene window
                }else if(observable.equals(this.heightProperty())){
                    double scale = height / 400; // 400 is initial size for stage height window
                    subScene.setHeight(250*scale); // 250 is initial size for subScene width
                }
            }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Ypu may want to use getTransforms().add(new Scale(parameter1, para2,...));